# moving focus to a specific previous input on enter, AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

there are 5 inputs, 2 at the top of page and three at the bottom, I'm using a custom directive to move focus to the next input by pressing enter on the three at the bottom. but when the focus is on the third (last) one, I need the focus to go back to one of the 2 inputs on the top when I press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-keypress` to call a function when a key is pressed.  In the function that is called you can reference `$event` for `keyCode`, `altKey`, etc. to limit it.

Here is an example of how to use `ng-keypress` and get the `keyCode` from `$event`:

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress='functionYouWantToCall($event)'>

$scope.functionYouWantToCall = function($event){
    var keyPressed = $event.keyCode;
    console.log(keyPressed);
}
```

From the function you can tell it to focus on the other inputs.

Comment: @SarahMoghaddam Can you upvote and accept it as the answer if this is what you were looking for?  Glad I could help!